# Security Exception requesting PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock, securityexception, android-securityexception

I wrote a library which starts a STICKY `Service` when the main application calls a specific method.
This Service acquires a `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` during the execution of the `onStartCommand()` method:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
if(powerManager != null) {
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, this.getClass().getName());
    wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

and the main application requires the `WAKE_LOCK` permission in its `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="it.mcampana.myapp">

<application
    ....>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

some activities...


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

</manifest>
```

(yes, there are a lot of permissions....but I need them!).

However, with some devices (e.g., samsung SM-G950F, or ASUS_Z017D) I receive from ACRA the following exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10182 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
```

at the exact point where the Service requires the `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`.
The strange thing is that with other devices (e.g., Xiaomi Mi 5, or Nexus 5) everything works fine.

**UPDATE: ** I found that this and other problems related to "missing permissions" (also with missing ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and READ_CALENDAR) mainly come from Samsung devices. As far as you know, there are some restrictions or additional security policies on Samsung devices?

Comment: Usually, the `<uses-permission>` elements go before `<application>`, though hopefully that is no longer a problem the way that it used to be. It's possible that these users are running some custom ROM or hacked version of your app that is messing with requesting wakelocks.

Comment: I'm sure that they use original ROMs made by manufacturers (Asus and Samsung). In addition, they use a debug version of my app downloaded from my personal website.

Answer (score 0):

In which API version are you testing? In API 26 and newer you should ask user for permissions during the runtime

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK},1);
```

then override onRequestPermissionsResult method to get the user response.

[check this out](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: `WAKE_LOCK` is not a `dangerous` permission and does not need to be requested at runtime.

Comment: As @CommonsWare wrote, this is not necessary for the WAKE_LOCK permission.

Comment: Humm... Sorry guys, I didn't know this runtime permissions should be asked only for dangerous permissions. we live and learn! Thank you!